# Difference between "show the ropes" and "learn the ropes"

Tags: word-choice, differences

When should I use "learn the ropes" and "show the ropes"? Are both of these expressions interchangeable?

Thanks

Comment: I can show you something in the hopes that you’ll learn it. But whether you do or not is a separate issue.

Comment: The same as that between *show* and *learn*. Need more help?

Comment: What's the difference between "show" and "learn"???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**show the ropes / learn the ropes**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/167402?redirectedFrom=show%20one%20the%20ropes#eid24921407)

> P5. to know the ropes: be experienced in or familiar with some
>   customary action, practice, etc. Also in to **learn** (also
>   understand) **the ropes**. Hence to **show** someone (also put someone
>   up to) **the ropes**: to teach or explain to someone the customary
>   ways of doing something.

Yes they are of the same sense, one to show and the other is to learn the ropes.  As in:

1948   E. Waugh *Loved One*

> Mr. Schultz had found a young man to take Dennis's place and Dennis
>   was spending his last week at the Happier Hunting Ground in **showing
>   him the ropes.**

and

2008   N.Y. Times

> It is clear that Mr. Zardari is going to be regent while his son
>   **learns the ropes.**

Comment: No they aren't the same, "to show someone the ropes" is to teach, "to learn the ropes" is to receive teaching. The only exception to this is some forms of dialect speech where "learn" is used to mean to give as well as to receive instruction. This leads, or at least used to lead,  to sentences like "Go along wi' Mr Smith, 'e'll learn thee what to do"

Comment: Isn't this difference the same as that between "show" and "know"?